# Play audio files in iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, audiotoolbox

I want to play sound in my application for that I am using .mp3 file type. It is working fine in Simulator but when I am lunching it to my device it is not working and not producing any sound can any one help me why it is not working on device or which file format is better to play audio file in iPhone and iPad?

```
NSURL *tapSound   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",SoundFileName] withExtension: @""];

// Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
 self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [tapSound retain];

 // Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
 AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
                     soundFileURLRef,
                    &soundFileObject
                    );

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```

**Above is mine code to play sound**

Thank you.

Comment: @user532445, Or if no one posted an acceptable answer, then post the answer to your own question that enabled you to move on in your development. This way you are giving back to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The system sound IDs won't play if the device is muted, so this is possibly the cause. (They're only really for the purpose of user interface effects such as alerts, etc. as per the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).)

As such, I'd be tempted to use the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) style approach. As a sample (no pun intended) implementation:

```
// *** In your interface... ***
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

...

AVAudioPlayer *testAudioPlayer;

// *** Implementation... ***

// Load the audio data
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_name" ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
NSError *audioError = nil;

// Set up the audio player
testAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];
[sampleData release];

if(audioError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
}
else {
    [testAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
    [testAudioPlayer play];
}



// *** In your dealloc... ***
[testAudioPlayer release];
```

You should also remember to set the appropriate audio category. (See the [AVAudioSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) `setCategory:error:` method.)

Finally, you'll need to add the AVFoundation library to your project. To do this, alt click on your project's target in the Groups & Files column in Xcode, and select "Get Info". Then select the General tab, click the + in the bottom "Linked Libraries" pane and select "AVFoundation.framework".

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would suggest using `AVAudioPlayer` instead of this, but you could try using this alternate code instead.  In your example it looks like you forgot to include the extension, which might be the problem also. The simulator is more lenient on naming, so if you forgot the extension it might play on the simulator and not a device.

```
SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (CFBundleGetMainBundle (),CFSTR ("sound"),CFSTR ("mp3"),NULL );
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject );
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
```